# FireBase and LiveData the text on in the cardviews don't appear and the content doesn't update (I can see the cards but there is no content)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata

I use Firebase Realtime Database. I have RecycleViewAdapter class, a Fragment which shows the recycleview, a ViewHolder class which gives data to the fragment (I use LiveData) and there is a Repository class which communicates with the firebase database.

```
class Post(
var title: String = "",
var dateStr: String = "",
var desc: String = "",
var id: String = "")
```

class PostsFireBaseRepository(val bucketListViewModel: BucketListViewModel) {

```
private val path: String = "posts"

init {
    initPostsListener()
}


fun getAllPosts() {
    var data = mutableListOf<Post>()
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid.toString())
        .child(path)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue<Post>(Post::class.java)
                    if (newPost != null) {
                        data.add(newPost)
                    }
                }
                bucketListViewModel.allPosts.value = data
                bucketListViewModel.dataChanged()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
```

}

```
     class BucketListViewModel() : ViewModel() {
        
             private val repository: PostsFireBaseRepository
        
             var recyclerViewAdapter: BucketListRecyclerViewAdapter? = null
        
             var allPosts: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Post>> = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Post>>()
        
    
         init {
              repository = PostsFireBaseRepository(this)
              repository.getAllPosts()
         }

      fun dataChanged() {
            recyclerViewAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

}

```
class BucketListFragment : Fragment(), DatePickerDialogFragment.OnDateSelectedListener,
BucketListRecyclerViewAdapter.PostItemClickListener {

private lateinit var bucketListViewModel: BucketListViewModel

private lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter: BucketListRecyclerViewAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bucketlist, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    setupRecyclerView()

    bucketListViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(BucketListViewModel::class.java)
    bucketListViewModel.allPosts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { posts ->
        recyclerViewAdapter.addAll(posts)
    }

}
```

BucketListRecyclerViewAdapter

```
class BucketListRecyclerViewAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<BucketListRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

interface PostItemClickListener {
    fun onItemLongClick(position: Int, view: View, post: Post?): Boolean
    fun onItemClick(position: Int, view: View, post: Post?): Boolean
}

private var postList = mutableListOf<Post>()

private var lastDeleted: Post? = null
private var lastDeletedPos: Int? = null

var postClickListener: PostItemClickListener? = null

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.bucketlist_post_row, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val post = postList[holder.adapterPosition]

    holder.post = post

    holder.tvTitle.text = post.title
    holder.tvDesc.text = post.desc
    holder.tvRowDate.text = post.dateStr
}

override fun getItemCount() = postList.size

fun addItem(post: Post) {
    postList.add(post)
    notifyItemInserted(postList.size-1)
}

fun addAll(posts: List<Post>) {
    postList.clear()
    postList.addAll(posts)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please also add the content of your  `Post` clas.

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onDataChange` method you will need to inform that adapter that its data is changed, otherwise it won't repaint the UI element. To do this, you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter after you've updated the data source for that adapter.

So something like:

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
        val newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue<Post>(Post::class.java)
        if (newPost != null) {
            data.add(newPost)
        }
    }
    bucketListViewModel.allPosts.value = data
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();        
}
```

Exactly how to reach the adapter depends on your code. For example, in your case you may have to add a method to the `BucketListViewModel` that you call from `onDataChange` and that then calls the adapter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work for me. Maybe something else is wrong with my code. I edited the code with the changes.
I added to the post the recycleview adapter class, where I call also call the notifyDataSetChanged function.